# Can HttpRequestBase be used in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I am trying to do this java code in Dart/Flutter. It is a connection **HttpRequestBase** from a library called **implementation "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"**.

Java example: Inside an activity called HttpPut.java there is a call to this library. Here is the specific part that I want to take to Dart.

```
protected HttpRequestBase getRequestBase(Request request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPut httpPost = new cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPut(
                request.getResource()
        );
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(request.getParameters(), "UTF-8");
        entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        return httpPost;
    }
```

The **Request** class contains the following:

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface Request {
    String getResource();

    String getParameters();

    Collection<String> getHeaders();
```

What I have tried in Dart is to call the library **http: ^ 0.12.1** but it is not exactly what I need. Because although I can do, in this case httpPut(...), I cannot perform the following steps such as **StringEntity**. How would you solve those problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Flutter [does allow you to insert platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) in your app, this is probably not what you want in this case. The classes/methods involved will not be the same, but you should be able to achieve what your Android code does with other classes/methods from Dart. Check out the [HttpClient class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html). Your code might be similar to this (though this snippet is missing request.getParameters(), since I'm not sure what that changes):

```
Future<HttpClientRequest> getRequestBase(Request request) async {
  HttpClientRequest httpRequest = await HttpClient().putUrl(Uri.parse(request.getResource()));
  httpRequest.headers.contentType = ContentType('aplication', 'json', charset: 'UTF-8');
  return httpRequest;
}
```

Then, when you want to actually send the request in your code and get the response, you can do

```
HttpClientRequest requestBase = await getRequestBase(request);
HttpClientResponse response = await requestBase.close();
```